# Country specific information for travellers using opendata api/dataset

Tags: data-request, data.gov, api

I want to get country specific information using api/dataset as shown on http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/france.html. How can I get this data?

Comment: If nothing else works, page scrape.

Comment: That is the last option if I will not found any open dataset regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

The Department of State's API covers security issues relating to travel, relations with countries - but not travel visa/passport requirements.

http://www.state.gov/developer/

The also have a humanitarian information unit that publishes maps and datasets about risk areas of the world: such as conflict in Syria and Ebola in West Africa.

https://hiu.state.gov

This is the State Department's XML feed on travel warnings:

http://cadatacatalog.state.gov/storage/f/2013-11-24T21%3A00%3A58.223Z/tws.xml