# Travel warnings

Tags: travel

Does anybody know a multi-country data source on travel warnings?

I've data sources that cover general travel restrictions during Corona, and data of travel from one country ([Country specific information for travellers using opendata api/dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/country-specific-information-for-travellers-using-opendata-api-dataset/3960#3960)), but not a more comprehensive data source of country-wise travel warnings.

Answer (score 1):

One resource that may work:

https://www.travel-advisory.info/data-api

> This API provides you with a daily updated list of country advisories. These advisories contain a risk value which describes how dangerous a country is from a travellers perspective. This data is available for every country and as fresh as this website.

They don't require a key, but ask for fair-use and attribution.

You can get a list of all countries: https://www.travel-advisory.info/api - which returns 238 country results.

I made a sample request:

https://www.travel-advisory.info/api?countrycode=CH

And this is the response (basic, but should be complete for all countries)

```
{
   "api_status":{
      "request":{
         "item":"ch"
      },
      "reply":{
         "cache":"cached",
         "code":200,
         "status":"ok",
         "note":"The api works, we could match requested country code.",
         "count":1
      }
   },
   "data":{
      "CH":{
         "iso_alpha2":"CH",
         "name":"Switzerland",
         "continent":"EU",
         "advisory":{
            "score":4,
            "sources_active":5,
            "message":"Switzerland has a current risk level of 4 (out of 5). We advise: Please reconsider your need to travel to Switzerland.",
            "updated":"2020-12-04 08:25:17",
            "source":"https:\/\/www.travel-advisory.info\/switzerland"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you go to the specific country page, e.g. https://www.travel-advisory.info/switzerland, then you'll see more details of the warning. But I don't think the API has that info.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful (+1), but what I was looking to have different travel warnings of each country. I believe this data is not openly available, at least I did not find it